# PHP parent and using it in code not in the class itself?

Tags: php, oop, parent, extends

I have 2 classes like

```
class A {
     public function B () {
         return 'b';
     }
}

class C extends A {
     public function D () {
         return 'd';
     }
}
```

I know that to use `function b` in `class C` I do,

```
class A {
     public function B () {
         return 'b';
     }
}

class C extends A {
     public function D () {
         $b = parent::B();
         return 'd';
     }
}
```

But what about when I initiate the object? Do I have to do (which works)

```
$c = new C();
$b = $c -> b();
```

Or do I still have to use this `parent` keyword?

I tried doing,

```
$c = new C();
$b = $c -> parent::B();
```

But it does not work.

Thanks

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do. It might be more clear if you used *foo*, *bar*, etc for method names instead of letters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need the `parent` keyword in the second example, since class `C` extends `A`, it inherits all of its member functions and variables. So, `$c->b();` is perfectly valid. Here is a [link](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php) to the documentation on the `extends` keyword, which states:

> Often you need classes with similar variables and functions to another
>   existing class. In fact, it is good practice to define a generic class
>   which can be used in all your projects and adapt this class for the
>   needs of each of your specific projects. To facilitate this, classes
>   can be extensions of other classes. **The extended or derived class has
>   all variables and functions of the base class** (this is called
>   'inheritance' despite the fact that nobody died) and what you add in
>   the extended definition.

Comment: Ok call so if I use a function from a parent inside a childs class function use the `parent` keyword if not just use it as normal? Thanks, I did read the doc but you made it clearer :)

Comment: Correct, you'll only need `parent` inside the actual class definition (as in, inside one of the child class's functions). Otherwise, just call the function on an object of the child class.

Answer (score 1):

When class `C` extends from `A`, you can use this to reach function `B()`:

```
class C extends A {
     public function D () {
         $b = $this->B();
         return 'd';
     }
}
```

And likewise, from an instantiated class `C` you should call it as you mentioned using `$c->B()`. The `parent::` construct is only meant to be used inside class methods; it can't be used outside of the class declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Use the one that works.

When an instance inherits functions they are directly callable from that object. The caller does not need to be aware of whether `b` is some function of `C` or if `c` inherited it from another class.